# Get Promise data out of it Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I try this:

```
var result = [];
promise.then(function (data) {
  result.push(data);

});
console.log(result)
```

and the result array is empty. Is there a way to get it out of the promise?

Comment: what's the `promise` show more code. Where did you define `promise`

Comment: Damn. Usually we answer this question by telling to use promises...

Comment: @Edwin It doesn't matter

Comment: Where are you running your code? Are you using any tools like babel-js? What are you tagetting?

Comment: Never mind then I don't get the question, I thought he was asking why is `result` empty

Comment: Oh nevermind, I get it but @dystroy you already answered.

Answer (score 1):

No, [you can't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/)

The point of promises is to allow a simple chaining of actions, some of them asynchronous.

You may do

```
var result = [];
promise.then(function (data) {
    result.push(data);
}).then(function(){
    console.log(result)
});
```

I'd suggest you to read [this introduction to promises](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#what-are-promises-and-why-should-i-use-them).

Answer (score 1):

Promises are sometimes referred to as *futures* or *future values*. You can't directly get the value *out of the promise* but you can get **a promise of a future value**, as seen below.

```
var futureResult = promise.then(function (data) {
    var result = [];
    result.push(data);
    return result;
});

futureResult.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});

futureResult.then(function (result) {
    console.log('another logger');
    console.log(result);
});
```